# Matching multiple properties in one Matcher

Tags: java, mockito, matcher, hamcrest

I need to write Matcher which will check multiple properties. For single property i've used:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasProperty;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;

    Matcher<Class> matcherName = Matchers.<Class> hasProperty("propertyName",equalTo(expectedValue));
```

how am I suppose to check more properties in one Matcher ?

Answer (score 25):

You can check for more properties using one matcher by combining matchers with `allOf`:

```
    Matcher<Class> matcherName = allOf(
        hasProperty("propertyName", equalTo(expected1)),
        hasProperty("propertyName2", equalTo(expected2)));
```

But I guess that what you are actually looking for is the `samePropertyValuesAs` one, that checks if a bean has the same property values as another one by checking the properties itself instead of the `equals` method:

```
    assertThat(yourBean, samePropertyValuesAs(expectedBean));
```

Comment: Yes, allOf is good way, but I cant use assertThat

i need to verify if object run method with expected parameter, like:
`verify(mock).method(argThat(matcherName));`

Comment: @Szympek `samePropertyValuesAs` is also a `Matcher` that you can assign to a variable: `Matcher<Class> matcherName = samePropertyValuesAs(expectedBean)`

Answer (score 5):

[Ruben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35439683/1426891) using [`allOf`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#allOf%28org.hamcrest.Matcher,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher%29) is the best way to combine matchers, but you may also choose to write your own matcher from scratch based on [BaseMatcher](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/BaseMatcher.html) or [TypeSafeMatcher](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher.html):

```
Matcher<Class> matcherName = new TypeSafeMatcher<Class>() {
  @Override public boolean matchesSafely(Class object) {
    return expected1.equals(object.getPropertyName())
        && expected2.equals(object.getPropertyName2());
  }
};
```

Though you do get unlimited power to write arbitrary matcher code without relying on reflection (the way that `hasProperty` does), you'll need to write your own `describeTo` and `describeMismatch`(`Safely`) implementations to get the comprehensive error messages that `hasProperty` defines and that `allOf` would aggregate for you.

You may find it wise to use `allOf` for simple cases involving a couple of simple matchers, but consider writing your own if matching a large number of properties or if implementing complex conditional logic.